# django: Generic Views without Templates

Tags: python, django, oop

AFAIK you need a template to use generic views in django.

Is there a way or third party app to use generic views without HTML templates?

I love the django admin interface, since you can use and configure it without writing HTML.

I prefer the object oriented way which is used in django admin to customize it. In most cases you can stay in nice python code, without any HTML/template files.

**Update**

The django admin uses templates. That's true. But everybody uses the same and proven templates from django.contrib.admin. With generic views everybody writes his own templates. I think this is a drawback and waste of time. Good and extensible default templates would be nice.

I guess someone has already a generic view system for django where you only need to use templates if you want to modify the default. But I could not find such an app with my favourite search engine.

Comment: Under the hood, Django administration uses templates. If you want your app to output HTML, I think the easiest way to go is to use templates.

Comment: If you don't mind using HttpResponse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538793/outputing-text-from-urls-py-in-django

Answer (score 1):

Templates need HTML. If you want to be generic I would Use a base template and then for each model and CRUD-Operation a partial That takes an object or list of objects and knows exactly how to render That model. The block notation also is good to arrange HTML content.

However, to write an standardized interface like the admin is a lot of Work and not appropriate for an Frontend.

From my Vantage point use TemplateTags and -Filters, Blocks, Use partials wherever you can and standardize your variables you pass to your Template.

This gives you a very pluggable Template system where you can reuse loads of you HTML code.