# Outputing text from urls.py in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Is there any way I can simply output text (not HTML) from urls.py instead of calling a function (in views.py or otherwise)?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', "Hello World"),
)
```

Comment: AFAIK no, but you can output text from the view.

Comment: I suppose you could use e.g. `lambda *a, **k: 'Hello World'`, but what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: It's just a little experiment I'm working on. Nothing production worthy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, definitly. A `url` must map a pattern to a callable, and this callable must accept a `HttpRequest` as first argument and return a `HttpResponse`.

The closer thing you could do would be to map the pattern to a lambda (anonymous function), ie:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', lambda request: HttpResponse("Hello World", content_type="text/plain")),
)
```

but I would definitly not consider this as good practice.

Comment: I found this works as well `url(r'^$', lambda request: HttpResponse("Hello World")),` which is nice. Not being a python pro can the statement be made more compact?

Comment: You could wrap it in a helper function. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `url` function takes a callable, so something like

```
rlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', lambda req:HttpResponse("Hello World")),
)
```

would work. There is really nothing gained in doing so though, except making your urls.py harder to read.

First, you should consider whether you really want this. If there is a need for it (I have never had a need to do this, and I've written a fair share of Django apps during the years), you could wrap this into something more compact, e.g.

Note that passing a string directly to `url` treats it as a method name.

```
def static_text(s):
    return lambda req:HttpResponse(s)

rlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', static_text("Hello World")),
)
```

Comment: what's the `lambda` for?

Comment: To create lambda function (http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk)

Comment: Ahhh. so the second part of the url function has to be a function hence you can't pass a string to it. Gotcha

Answer (score 1):

For Django 2.2 and above

`path('', lambda request: HttpResponse("Hello World", content_type="text/plain"), name='home'),`