# Can you have a view function in your URLS.py file

Tags: python, django

This is just an academic question. I don't intend this for production but can you put a view function above your url routes in your url.py file? Something like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello_world(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World!")

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'hello_world'),
)
```

Comment: Yes you can. You can also write it as a lamda functions in the url parameters Eg: url(r'^$', lambda hello_world: HttpResponse("Hello World!"))

Comment: Funny you should mention that. It's very similar to my last question (what are the chances) > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538793/outputing-text-from-urls-py-in-django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the view can be in your urls file, although I wouldn't recommend it as a way to organise your Django project.

However, in the `url()` you should use the view itself, not a string.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', hello_world),
]
```

Providing string view arguments e.g. `'myproject.urls.hello_world'` is deprecated in Django 1.8 and removed in Django 1.10.

The view argument can be any callable, you can even use a lambda function (again, I wouldn't recommend it).

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', lambda req: HttpResponse("Hello World"),
]
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of testing it without the quote marks (doh!)